# bootstrap dropdown menu artifacts

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Sometimes there is - sometimes no

```
<th id="DateTime" class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="DateTime">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                @Html.DisplayName("DateTime")
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="DateTime">
                <li><a asp-action="SortingByDate" asp-controller="Project" asp-route-sorting="@SortingEnum.Increasing">Sorting inc.</a></li>
                <li><a asp-action="SortingByDate" asp-controller="Project" asp-route-sorting="@SortingEnum.Decreasing">Sorting dec.</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#filterDateTime" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="filter" class="filterDateTime">Filter</a>
                </li>
                <li><a asp-action="HideColumn" asp-controller="Project" asp-route-column="@ProjectColumnsEnum.EntryDateTime">Hide column</a></li>
            </ul>
```

So it should look like:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8nc7.png)

So it looks actually (basically after ctrl-f5):
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpZox.png)

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title> - QAManagementTool</title>


    <link href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/lib/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/lib/bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/lib/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

......

```
<script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script src="/js/TestRequirementList.js"></script>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: I will add, the problem appears only in the Edge Browser. Sometimes by itself, but always after ctrl-f5

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add list-unstyled after `class="dropdown-menu list-unstyled" lise this. Here you remove your bulluts. Then you have to wrap css property for list

```
.dropdown-menu{
 padding:0;//are margin 0
}
```

Here `padding:0;//are margin 0 is my css code.If you wrap you own css property`

Comment: My own styles are not there. "Padding = 0" does not solve the problem. https://i.gyazo.com/6fa17f54e3fbcdb622278f3d70dc6905.png I tested it many times - the problem is only in the EDGE browser. It does not always appear, I do a reset(ctrl-f5) so that the problem appears.